# How to implode 2 dimensional array into square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I would like to output my php array into this format: [1991, 6.5], [1992, 4], [1993, 5.9]

PHP array:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $metals[] = array('year' => $row['year'], 
                    'metal' => $row['metal'];
}
```

I have seen some examples of implode function but I couldn't find any that could match what I want to do.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your array look like?

Comment: what is the second value? I mean 6.5 or 4 or 5.9?

Comment: The `$metals` associative array you show has three elements. The desired output indicates only two and no keys.

Comment: My apologies. I would only like to have an output of 2 elements in each array. When I do a echo $aluminas;, the output is only Array.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($metals as $metal){
    $tmp[] = '['.implode(",", $metal).']';
}
$formatted_output = implode(",", $tmp);
print_r($formatted_output);
```

Comment: the output becomes [array, array, array, array, array],[array, array, array, array, array]. 
I have no idea how it becomes 5 elements in a single array.

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball suggests you want to generate JSON for an AJAX thingie. If so, i's as easy as this:

```
<?php

$metals = array();
$metals[] = array(1991, 6.5);
$metals[] = array(1992, 4);
$metals[] = array(1993, 5.9);

echo json_encode($metals);

?>
```

Which prints:

```
[[1991,6.5],[1992,4],[1993,5.9]]
```

Comment: Hi Alavaro, you are right about what I plan to do. However, I have more hundreds of records. I'm looking at the direction of creating a while loop to output data in that format. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: And how do you go about removing the quotes from within. Currently, I have ["1991", "5.6"], ["1992", "6"]. Thanks Alvaro.

Comment: That's because those values are strings. Cast them to integers or floats when reading them: `(int)$foo`, `(float)$bar`

Comment: Your crystal ball rocks, note that each array needs to be an array to get square brackets around each value set.

Answer (score 1):

array_map is a call back function, where you can play with the passed array!
this should work.

```
$str = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el['tag_id']; }, $arr));
```